# Php script returning array array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, file-put-contents

I have created an php script in order to read data send from an android app to php and save it in file but upon opening the text file i'm getting following statement :-

> ArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArray

instead of data could somebody tell me where iam going wrong and how can i rectify it ?

Here is my php script :-

```
<?php

$password="";
$user="root";
$database="shadowpets";
$host="localhost";
$response=array();
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database)or die("Unable to connect");
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
{


    if(isset($_POST['OrderSummary']))
    {

        $data=$_POST['OrderSummary'];
        $json=json_decode($data,true);
        $file='text.txt';
        $result=file_put_contents($file,$json);


            $response["success"]=1;
            $response["message"]="done";


    }
    else
    {
        $response["success"]=0;
        $response["message"]="parameters not correctl formatted";
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
}
    ?>
```

Comment: What's in the script? How are you presenting the data?

Comment: please show your code

Comment: How should we know what you are doing wrong if we don't know your code? Please read [ask].

Comment: sorry i just updated code please see the code and help me out

Comment: Well... You are `json_decoding` a (unknown) vaue with the second parameter `true`. So it's pretty safe to assume `$json` is in fact an array and not a `json`-string

Comment: What did you expect from writing an array value to a file?

Comment: first the array was getting written to the file but now  it is retruning this

Comment: As your `json_decode` returns an array and not null it's safe to assume you just can write `$result=file_put_contents($file, $_POST['OrderSummary']);` as `$_POST['OrderSummary']` contains a valid `json`-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$json` is an multidimension array, while function `file_put_contents()` only accept a string, array, or stream as the data content. When the array is one dimension array, it store each element of the array. When the array is multidimension array, it will cause,

> PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /home/xxxxx/test.php on
>   line xx

You can test simple demo, which will store `ArrayArrayArray` in the aaa.txt file. And the number of 'Array' is lenth of the multidimension array `count([[1,2,3,4],[2],[3]])` which is 3.

```
<?php
file_put_contents("aaa.txt", [[1,2,3,4],[2],[3]]);
```

Comment: the problem is solved i want to know how can i read it's element and store it in the database

Comment: This answer can't be true as OP does `file_put_contents($file, json_decode($_POST['OrderSummary'], true));`. If `$_POST['OrderSummary']` was indeed a (multidimensional) array the output in his file would empty as  [`json_decode([[],], true)`](https://ideone.com/ki9o12) returns `NULL`

Comment: @DarkBee Here I make a mistake, I just want to say OP use a multidimension array as the parameter of `file_put_contents` which cause the issue.

Comment: @KrisRoofe True, but storing a multidimensional array in a file will only output one `Array` in it. OP is prolly using `FILE_APPEND` in his/her original code. Nonetheless OP ain't clear on what he/she want.

Comment: @DarkBee You can test the demo in the answer.

Comment: @DarkBee the number of `Array` is the first dimension. In you demo code, the first dimension of your array is 1.

Comment: @KrisRoofe Point taken there

Answer (score -1):

Check for print_r($_POST['OrderSummary']) before writing into file. Must be array,

Comment: Should be a comment

Comment: thanks for your suggestion as i want to read the contents of the array and then store it in the database could you suggest me anyway to do it ?

Comment: Frankly , i dont know nothing about the content of $_POST['OrderSummary'], 
If you want to get the whole content as string , use implode on this array.